# Using enum datatype in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have declared an enum datatype like:

```
typedef enum TagTypes
{
   BUTTON_TAG_1 = 1,
   BUTTON_TAG_2,
   BUTTON_TAG_3,
   NEW_TAG

}ButtonTag;

typedef enum TagType
{
   LABEL_TAG_1 = 1,
   LABEL_TAG_2,
   NEW_TAG
}LabelTag;
```

I wanted to find the corresponding tag of the button or label through this tag value as

`(clickedbutton.tag == ButtonTag.BUTTON_TAG1)` or `(changingLabel.tag == LabelTag.LABEL_TAG_1)`

but this syntax doesn't seem to be possible in Obj C, it throws me error saying Expected Identifier or ")"

Is there a way i can select tagNames by specifying tagDatatype like:

```
LabelTag.LABEL_TAG_2, ButtonTag.BUTTON_TAG2, ...
```

Thanks for any help

clickedbutton.tag == BUTTON_TAG1 will work, but I prefer to use it like tagName.tagValue , so that i can have same tagValues for different tag sets say tagValue "NEW_TAG" in both LabelTag and ButtonTag.

Comment: are you not getting error: redeclaration of enumerator?

Comment: @ParagBafna: Is there any way to get around that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it follows the same convention as it does in C where you just write

```
if (clickedbutton.tag == BUTTON_TAG1)
```

without specifying the enum type. You only have to specify the type when its a variable.

Comment: yes, that will work, but I prefer to use it like tagName.tagValue , so that i can have same tagValues for different tag sets say tagValue "NEW_TAG" in both LabelTag and ButtonTag.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Paulthiravium since there is already a sufficient answer, I'd like to add that a tag is an integer typ. So all you've got to do is to initialize your buttons properly: `button1.tag = BUTTON_TAG_1`. And since you're using an enum you may like rename the tag's names to something more meaningful, else you're trading a number for a symbol named as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apple's headers. They simply prefix all enum entries with the enum's name, e.g. `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` in the enum `UIViewAnimationCurve`. I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `switch-case`

```
switch(LabelTag)
{
   case : LABEL_TAG_1

   break;

   case : LABEL_TAG_2

   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use the form of LabelTag::LABEL_TAG_2 you can use objective-c++ mode (change your file extension to `.mm`) and do this:

```
class FirstEnum
{
    public: 
    enum { a, b, c } ;
} ;

class SecondEnum
{
    public:
    enum { a, b, c } ;
} ;
```

Then in your code can can refer to `LabelTag::a` for example.